# How to read 16 bytes each from a File in C using for loop

Tags: c

I need to read 16 bytes each (because I need to cipher each block of 16 bytes individually) using for loop its not working. Can't figure out where am missing it :(

my complete code

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
FILE *fp;
BYTE buffer[16] = {0x00}; 
int i;
int lastBlock;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lastBlock = fileSize - 16;
    printf("FileSize %d \n", fileSize);
    printf("Lastblcok %d \n", lastBlock);
    for(x = 0;  x < lastBlock;  i+16){
        fread(buffer, 1, 16, fp);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);     
    }
    return(0);
}
```

What's my mistakes ? Last block variable is fine. It prints out rubbish. It's just a plain text file.

Comment: What's in your file? Show the code from when you open it.

Comment: Your assuming each byte block is a nulchar-terminated string, for starters. And if you want to read in 16-byte chunks *strictly* you should be reading 16,1 not 1,16

Comment: Where to start... what does "not working" mean? What is `buffer`? Where do you ensure it's a proper, null-terminated string? What about short reads? etc etc etc

Comment: Please don't paste walls of code in comments. *Update your question*.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my post to include all my code listings.

Comment: To answer your immediate question, the biggest mistake of all is *not checking your api return values for error detection.*

Answer (score 4):

You have your inner 2 parameters backwards.  You are trying to read 16 blocks that are 1 byte each, instead of reading 1 block that is 16 bytes.  You are also not doing any error checking to make sure `fread()` actually reads everything you told it to read.

Regarding your loop limiting variable `lastBlock`, it is not being calculated correctly. If the file were, say 100 bytes long, and you wanted to read it in whole-16-byte blocks *only*, you would read 6 blocks (`100/16`). Your calculation, (`100 - 16`),  would *attempt* to read 84 blocks, and fail miserably after the first 6.

Try something more like this:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x, numRead;
    BYTE buffer[16];
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fileSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("FileSize %d \n", fileSize);
    for(x = 0; x < fileSize; x += 16) {
        numRead = fread(buffer, 1, 16, fp);
        if (numRead < 1) {
            printf("error\n");
            break;
        }
        if (numRead < 16) {
            memset(&buffer[numRead], 0, 16-numRead);
        }
        printf("%.*s\n", numRead,buffer);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks alot. It worked but how do I know how many byte is yet to be read ? I need to know that because I need to pad to 16 byte and then do another read. Thanks

Comment: If `fread()` does not read a full 16-byte block, then either an error occurred, or more likely EOF was reached. Either way, you would stop reading.  So what exactly are you trying to "pad ... and then do another read" for? If you are expecting the last block to be less than 16 bytes, then you can easily determine that by taking the file size modulo 16. Or, you can go back to asking `fread()` to read 16 1-byte blocks instead of 1 16-byte block, and then pay attention to the retuen value to know when it reads less than 16 bytes, indicating the last block was read.

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential problems with this code:

1) You're not checking the error status for a failed read

2) You're not terminating the string

SUGGESTION:

```
char buffer[17];
...
for(x = 0;  x < lastBlock; x++){
    /* int fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, FILE *stream); */
    if ((err = fread(buffer, 16, 1, fp)) < 0) {
      perror ("Read error!\n");
    }
    else {
      buffer[16] = '\0';
      printf("%s\n", buffer);   
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Last block variable is fine. It prints out rubbish."*

*Rubbish* because :

The `fread` function will just reads a number of elements, it doesn't terminate the string with null character

You can add the NULL (`'\0'`) terminator yourself or can use `fgets` / `fscanf` instead.

Comment: The file is more than 16 bytes. I want to read 16bytes each time until i complete reading the file. E.g. 0 - 15 bytes then 16 - 31 bytes etc. Also lastblock isn't the end of the file. I don't want to read all the file. Just want to read up until lastblock. Thanks